# Grade 9th middle school question

Tags: statistics

the mean of 5 apple is $12$, the range of the biggest and the lowest is $6$. If every apple is subtracted by $a$ then the sum is divided by $b$, the new mean is $2$ and the range of the biggest and the lowest is $3$. Find $a$ and $b$.

Comment: "the mean of 5 apple is 12"

Comment: @Oliver yes it is xD, but I am confused about what's a and b :(.

Comment: @Jeniffer What he means is that "the mean of $5$ apple is $12$" doesn't mean anything. Are the "apples" just pieces of data? For instance measurements of the sizes of the applies or something? So the mean of those $5$ measurements is $12$?

Comment: In any case, $a$ and $b$ are unknowns, that's the point of the problem. You're supposed to figure out what they are from the information you're given.

Comment: I don't get it.

Comment: Let me guess what you mean.  You have five values (v.g the weight in ounces of five apples).  Those five values have a mean of $12$ and a distribution of $\pm6$.  Right?  What happen with mean and distribution if each of those values are substracted by the same amount $a$?  What happen with mean and distribution if they are divided by the same amount $b$?

Comment: I have no idea how to subtract a number from an apple.

Answer (score 2):

ok I am going to answer this question assuming that it is measuring a piece of information about the apple that has a mean of 12. It could be the number of apples in a batch, it could be the diameter, or radius but the answer will still be the same

So we have a data set: $\{v,w,x,y,z\}$

$v$ is the mesaurement of the first apple, $w$ is the measurement of the second apple and so on.

we know that the following

$\frac{v+w+x+y+z}{5}=12$ and $z-v=6$

when we do the changes, our new data set is: $\{\frac{v-a}{b},\frac{w-a}{b},\frac{x-a}{b},\frac{y-a}{b},\frac{z-a}{b}\}$

And we know that from that data set we have the following (I have simplified the equations):

$\frac{v+w+x+y+z-5a}{5b}=2$ and $\frac{z-v}{b}=3$

In the second one, we know that $z-v=6$ from the previous equation so we can substitute that in and find that $b=2$

We can also factor out the original mean from the third equation and get the following:

$\frac{1}{b}\times(\frac{v+w+x+y+z}{5}-\frac{5a}{5})=2$

We can substitute that mean inside with $12$ and $b$ with $2$

$\frac{1}{2}\times(12-a)=2$

$6-\frac{a}{2}=2$

$-\frac{a}{2}=-4$

$a=8$

Therefore we have found that $a, b=8,2$

If you need help understanding this just ask

Comment: Did I do something wrong to get a different answer from Oleg?